# Add a new object to my page using angular showing in the *ngFor?

Tags: html, angular, api

I want to add a new movie object to my page showing like the others I already got from an api (with text and button like picture below) and be able to not see them it anymore when I reload the page.

What I am exactly trying to do is when I click on the ADD A MOVIE button get a modal, fill it and add the movie to my page showing like the other movies I got.

Please check my code below ...

data.service.ts

```
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { Movie } from './model/movie.model';
import {catchError, tap, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  private MOVIES: Movie[] = [
    {imdbID:"1", Title: 'Avatar', Year: 2009, Director: 'James Cameron', Genre:'Fiction', Runtime: '176min'},
  ];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  getMovies() {
    return fetch('https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=batman&apikey=9fa6058b')
    .then(function (resp) {
      return resp.json()
    });
  }

  getMovieById(imdbID:string) {
    return this.http.get<Movie[]>(imdbID);
  }


  updateMovie(movie:Movie) {
    return this.http.put(movie.imdbID, movie);
  }

  createMovie(movie:Movie) {
    return this.http.post('', movie);
  }
}
```

movie-list.component.ts

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DataService } from './../data.service';
import { Movie } from './../model/movie.model';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-list',
  templateUrl: './movie-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-list.component.css']
})
export class MovieListComponent implements OnInit {

  movies: Movie[];

  constructor(private dataService:DataService, private router: Router){}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.dataService.getMovies()
      .then(res => this.movies = res.Search);
  }

  addMovie() {
    this.movies.push(new Movie())
  }
}
```

add-movie.component.ts

```
import { Movie } from './../model/movie.model';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DataService } from './../data.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-movie',
  templateUrl: './add-movie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-movie.component.css']
})
export class AddMovieComponent implements OnInit {

  movies:Movie[];

  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder, private dataService:DataService, private router: Router) { }

  addForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      imdbID: [],
      Title: ['', Validators.required],
      Year: ['', Validators.required],
      Director: ['', Validators.required],
      Genre: ['', Validators.required],
      Runtime: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
      // this.movies.push(this.addForm.value);
      this.dataService.createMovie(this.addForm.value)
      .subscribe( data => {
        this.router.navigate(['movie-list']);
      });
    }
```

movie-list.component.ts

```
h3>List of Movies:</h3>


<div class="card" *ngFor="let movie of movies">
  <div class="card-header">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{movie.Poster}}" alt="Card image cap">
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">{{movie.Title}}</h4>
    <h4>{{movie.Year}}</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">Edit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="deleteMovie(movie.imdbID)" >Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the modal opens, fill in everything and add the movie to my list of movies.
The thing is that the movies showing already come from an api so how can I add a movie not on the api but on my page itself??

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why dont you send it to the database ?

Comment: How do I do so? how do i send it to the database?

Comment: You can store the list you are getting from api in a porperty`(movies: Movie[];)` in your service and then use that to show in html view and can modify also using form also.

Comment: So just for my understanding. You get the movie data from a public API or your own database ? If you get it from an API, adding new movies could get tricky. You would have to work with their API , wich might not be possible. 


You can also just do it in angular but the data will be lost when you reload the page

Comment: I get the data from a public api and I don't want to add new movies to their api. I want to add movies just with angular and lose the data when I reload the page. its just a basic CRUD website to make my buttons work. Right now trying to make my ADD button work. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen your code on stackblitz and observed that you need to do some changes to your existing code to make it work. Following are the changes you need.

1. You need to import `FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule` from angular forms in your `app.module.ts` using `import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';` and place these imports in your imports array of AppModule
2. In your `movie-list.component.ts`, comment this piece of the code
   `this.dataService.getMovies().then(res => this.movies = res.Search);` from the ngOnInit method. So, you will not see the movies from your API and will see the only movie (Avatar) you declared in your `data.service.ts`.
3. Remove the slice method from your `getAll()` method in `data.service.ts`.
4. In your `add-movie.component.html`, there is no means to trigger the `(ngSubmit)` event. So, you need to add `type="submit"` to your Add Button.
   Also, you need to add brackets to your formGroup as  `[formGroup]="addForm"`

With the above changes, when you add any movie,you can see it rendered on the movie list.

It really took some time to find these. Please let me know if they worked for you.

All this is just for your testing purposes. You need to post it to the API if you want your movies on their API.

I even edited your stackblitz code but could not put it here.

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help but it does not seem to work for me ... can you please post your stackblitz? I did everything you said but nothing changes... and how can i show both the movies on my database and the ones on the api at once? see all of them at the same time?

Comment: @AvaSahal, Can you please send the stackblitz with the changes I mentioned?

Comment: @AvaSahal, I have seen your code but you have not done few things I mentioned. You removed ngSubmit event in add-movie.component.html which you should not. Also, I asked you to remove the .slice() only in the getAll() method and you commented the entire  method. In movie.list.component.ts, ngOninit Method, let this.movies = this.dataService.getAll(); be there uncommented

Comment: @AvaSahal, Can I have the code with the first version without the changes I mentioned.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cakhuj .. I also did everything as your asked but not working either ..

Comment: @AvaSahal, it seems your Add a movie is not showing the modal. Please make it work and update the code and also you need to button a '>' at the <button > tag for Add

Comment: Can you check now why its showing the movie card when I add one but not the details of the movie? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cakhuj

Comment: @AvaSahal, I saw your latest stackblitz. Give me some time to make it work. It seems this is the initial version

Comment: Ok great thanks so much for you help !! Let me know of you find a solution

Comment: Great ... thank you so much ... Do you know how I can make the edit button work? or just to be able to see the details of the movie in the input when I click on edit?

Comment: @AvaSahal, I have updated the code to send the edited movie to the edit-movie-component. You need to fill the edit form with the input value and update it and send it back to the movie list component through event emitter

Answer (score 0):

Here I made a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c7q9xp

But using an array as an in-memory storage should only be used for training purposes. In a real application you should really implement a backend api with a own database.

EDIT:

To add a movie from your code you would do that in your submit method:

```
 onSubmit() {
     const movie = this.addForm.value as Movie;
     // you need to generate a uuid for every new entry
     movie.imbdID = uuid.v4();
     crudService.add(movie);
    }
```

Comment: Ok this is great but how do can I add a movie without having a const for movie with the details already filled??

Comment: I edited my answer to show you an example with the code you provided

Comment: I uploaded my code on stackblitz ... can you please have a look at my errors and why it is not working please? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cakhuj